# Config file throws error while deploying

Tags: 2010, deployment, error, configuration

I've created a new config-file "TimerJobs.config" which stores all my values for the timerjob (of course...) This file is located under the Layouts/random folder.

The problem I'm having, is when I deploy, I get an error:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': An error occurred
>   loading a configuration file: The parameter 'exePath' is invalid.
>   Parameter name: exePath

Anyone who knows the solution to this one?

FYI, the configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="TIMERJOB_MEETING_EXECUTE_ON_ACTIVATE" value="true" />
    <add key="TIMERJOB_MEETING_START" value="1" />
    <add key="TIMERJOB_MEETING_END" value="59" />
    <add key="TIMERJOB_MEETING_INTERVAL" value="5" />
    <add key="TIMERJOB_MEETING_SCHEDULE" value="Minute" />
    <add key="TIMERJOB_MEETING_DEBUG_MODE" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**Solution**

The problem was not to deploy the timerjob, the problem was in activating the feature (which creates the timerjob and reads from the config file)
Since there was a problem with getting the file, the feature always failed while activating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error indicates that it doesnt like the url (absolute path) to the config file ratha than the config file itself! Check to make sure that the file(config) in 14hive has the correct permission!

how are you calling that file?